# How to display orders using ListOrdersSample.php of amazon MWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

**Hi**
I have successfully posted the product in amazon by using the Feed API's.
And im displaying it by using Product API. 
Now I want to fetch orders from my amazon account, I do not know how a order will come into my amazon account, because my products are not on real amazon.

Any how im using **Orders API's** to get the orders, in that i had done all the configuration in the config file.
When i Run **ListOrdersSample.php** from my browser i get this..

> Service Response ============================================================================= 2016-05-30T10:33:56Z 7cc5f86a-ec24-4d36-a900-fa21db182bf1 ResponseHeaderMetadata: RequestId: 7cc5f86a-ec24-4d36-a900-fa21db182bf1, ResponseContext: F8uplH1mr6LUvjmxUr81VMn7SfvW93P/jNGwvRnzFVcM9SmGP/HrET+C0oLTOdNaBiMieGX/fz8k W/bb/d+e4A==, Timestamp: 2016-05-30T10:35:55.939Z, Quota Max: , Quota Remaining: , Quota Resets At:

Here is the code im running of **ListOrdersSample.php**.

```
<?php

  require_once('.config.inc.php');


  // Europe
  $serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";

   $config = array (
     'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
     'ProxyHost' => null,
     'ProxyPort' => -1,
     'ProxyUsername' => null,
     'ProxyPassword' => null,
     'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
   );

   $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client(
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
          APPLICATION_NAME,
          APPLICATION_VERSION,
          $config);

   ***********************************************************************/
   // @TODO: set request. Action can be passed as MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrders
   $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersRequest();
   $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
   $request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
   $request->setCreatedAfter('2016-04-01');
   // object or array of parameters
   invokeListOrders($service, $request);


    function invokeListOrders(MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface $service, $request)
    {
        try {
          $response = $service->ListOrders($request);

          echo ("Service Response\n");
          echo ("=============================================================================\n");

          $dom = new DOMDocument();
          $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
          $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
          $dom->formatOutput = true;
          echo $dom->saveXML();
          echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");

       } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Exception $ex) {
          echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
          echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
          echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
          echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
          echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
          echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
          echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
       }
   }
```

Please help me to solve this.. Thank u.

Comment: Can any one help me in this???

Comment: Looks like the date format used in setCreatedAfter is wrong and it should be ISO 8601format according to http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/orders/2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html